# Joomla module not showing

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

Am I missing something, the module below is published/enabled yet it still does not show on the page.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you select any available position from a template ?

Even if it's easy, this tutorial could be helpful for other people who find this question:

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/joomla/adding-new-menus-and-other-modules